# Exception deploying multi-device app to RaspBerry Pi 3 with Emteria OS

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, c++builder

For testing purpose, I try the Emteria OS on a Raspberry Pi 3. The Emteria version is 0.6.1 based on 7.1 android version.

With C++ builder I create a simple multi-device project. The form only contains a label. I try to deploy the app to my RaspBerry Pi targetting Android platform and using ADB through ethernet.

When the app executes in the RaspBerry Pi, I saw an EContext3DException. I try to research why I reach this exception through the net but I can't find interesting information about this exception.

[image: Emteria Exception]

So I don't know if the problem resides in the OS or I miss a configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Emteria reply, there were some incompatibility between Raspberry GPU wich uses OpenGL 2.0 and RAD Studio.

Seems to be the same problem until Raspberry support OpenGL 3.0 because I don't think that embarcadero is go to invest time with the OpenGL 2.0 library compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this. This workaround was comunicated through the emteria forum by SanderK.

You need to locate the file **FMX.Context.GLES.pas** in your source folder of your embarcadero installation directory and find the line with the code:

`if Flag <> GL_NO_ERROR then`

Replace this line with:

`if (Flag <> GL_NO_ERROR) and (Flag <> GL_INVALID_VALUE) then`

After that you need to add this modified file in your project and then compile.